# Refresh textbox after submitting the data

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm new to vb.net, and I'm sorry if this is very simple to you guys. I was wondering if there is a way to refresh the web page after I click a button that update the data in the sql.

The user will have to input some text in the textbox and click the button. The sql will update the current records and I would like to show the new record, which the user just entered in the textbox, along with the existing record.

Here's my code:

```
Protected Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click

    If txtReply.Text <> "" Then

        Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MYcloudConnection").ConnectionString
        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

        Dim ii As Integer = lblID.Text
        Dim ans As String
        ans = txtReply.Text

        Try
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection

            'to sent message
            myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE MESSAGE SET messageText = @M WHERE messageID = '" & ii & "'"
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("M", SqlDbType.NVarChar))
            myCommand.Parameters("M").Value = hihi.Text & "|Client:" & ans

            Dim i As Integer = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If i <> 0 Then
                MsgBox("Insert Successful")
            Else
                MsgBox("Insert Failed")
            End If

        Catch sqlex As SqlException
            MsgBox("Sql Exception:" & sqlex.Message.ToString())

        Catch divz As DivideByZeroException
            MsgBox("Divide by Zero Exception:" & divz.Message.ToString())

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())

        Finally
            myConnection.Close()
        End Try
    Else
        MsgBox("Cannot be Empty!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Start by turing on Option Strict: `Dim ii As Integer = lblID.Text` is assigning Text/String to an integer.  The subject of the WHERE clause should be a parameter too.  If you use `ExecuteNonQuery` the DB is updated but you will have to requery to get the new info from the DB.  If you want something more dynamic, use a DataAdapter and DataTable

Comment: @Plutonix Do you mean that i have to call the sql statement to reload the data into the text box after click the button ?

Comment: Not really - the textbox(es) already has the data doesnt it?  If you want/need to get new data added, you either have to requery, or use a DataAdapter and DataTable.  (you dont *have to* the Q sounds like you *want* to).

Comment: i have two text box, one (txtReply) is to get input, another (txtMessage) is to show the text. I was able to update/insert the text from (txtReply) into the database. now my problem is that, i want to refresh or reload the textbox to get the new data. sorry for the confused

Comment: Incidentally, `myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("M", SqlDbType.NVarChar))` needs to use "@M" for the parameter name, as does the following line, and you should pass the value for `messageID` through a parameter too.

Comment: You just need to query the DB after the update then set the textbox to the result.  Some problems I see with this however, you cant assume that the record you just inserted is always going to be the last one inserted, unless this is a single user application.  I would suggest looking at a stored procedure instead of a direct update, that way during the procedure you can properly get the data you want.  Alternatively you could simply set the text of the second box to the text of the first box and clear the text of the first box.